# Delete from database using Prepared Statement

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I'm want to delete a person from the database "person" on a given id. It works if I don't use Prepared Statement (the first 5 unmarked lines of code in the try-statement).

But when I try to do it using Prepared Statement it does not work, and I can´t figure out why?

The application gets stuck on prepStatement.executeUpdate();
Therefore I can't even see the value of executeUpdate (if I want to se how many Changes that are made).

I have a similar method, addPerson, where Prepered Statement works perfect. This really confuses me...

I appreciate your help.

```
   private void removePerson() {        
        int id = Integer.parseInt(idField.getText());

        PreparedStatement prepStatement = null;
        try {
           */* Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
              String sql = "DELETE FROM person WHERE id = '"+id+"'";                
              statement.executeUpdate(sql);
              System.out.println("Person removed from database...");
              ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            */*

              String sql = "DELETE FROM person WHREE id = ?";
              prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
              prepStatement.setInt(1, id);
              prepStatement.executeUpdate();
              System.out.println("Person removed from database...");
          }
          catch (SQLException se) {
              se.toString();
          }
          finally {
              try {
                  prepStatement.close();
              } 
              catch (SQLException ex) {
                  ex.toString();
              }
          }
    }
```

Comment: Typo?: `DELETE FROM person WHERE id = ?`

Comment: Original line, to clarify what Reimeus pointed out: String sql = "DELETE FROM person WHREE id = ?"; The rest of the code looks OK on first glance.

Comment: Oops, seems like thats where the error is!

Comment: Thank you guys for pointing that out, I can't Believe I didn't notice that...